# Local Notifications in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, local

In iOS, a "Local Notification" is used by an app when it is in the background, to inform the user that something has happened, that they might want to pay attention to:

> Local notifications ... to inform users when new data becomes available for your app, even when your app is not running in the foreground. For example, a messaging app might let the user know when a new message has arrived, and a calendar app might inform the user of an upcoming appointment.

[Apple dev - Local and Remote Notifications Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/)

[Its "local" if the app itself is providing the new data; "remote" if a remote server is sending the update.]

Is there an equivalent on Android?

Comment: This appears to be the oldest asking of this question; it is linked to from at least one later version of the question, and variants of the question have been asked at least 4 times. Therefore, I have rewritten it to make it less vague, and voted to reopen it. IMHO, it is a fundamental mobile feature; the question deserves to be asked and answered. [Alternatively, could close it as a duplicate of a later variant, if that has better answers, since no answer was accepted here. Google "stackoverflow android local notification"]

Comment: Two useful answers on other threads:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8590724/199364,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31946656/199364 - from these we see that Android doesn't have the direct equivalent of the iOS feature "local notification". Several different Android APIs are mentioned as possibly involved in a solution. Therefore I understand if the consensus is that this is still "too broad", though I personally would like to see, gathered in one place, possible alternatives for "app in background, how should we tell user something important has happened?"

Answer (score 54):

Use NotificationCompat.Builder if you are targeting old APIs too.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, HomeActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);

    b.setAutoCancel(true)
     .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
     .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())         
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
     .setTicker("Hearty365")            
     .setContentTitle("Default notification")
     .setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
     .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
     .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
     .setContentInfo("Info");


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());
```

Comment: Good working example. I followed other sample code and it worked with lollipop or greater versions. But this code works on kitkat also (I don't know why... maybe the Icon or defaults?) Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**If you want to fire local notification with big data i.e., with multiline text in single notification with title, Ticker, icon, sound.. use following code.. I think it will help you..**

```
   Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
            ReminderListActivity.class);



    notificationIntent.putExtra("clicked", "Notification Clicked");
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); // To open only one activity


        // Invoking the default notification service 

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        Uri uri = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Reminder");
        mBuilder.setContentText("You have new Reminders.");
        mBuilder.setTicker("New Reminder Alert!");
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.clock);
        mBuilder.setSound(uri);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        // Add Big View Specific Configuration 
        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        String[] events = null;

            events[0] = new String("Your first line text ");
            events[1] = new String(" Your second line text");



        // Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("You have Reminders:");

        // Moves events into the big view
        for (int i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
        }

        mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app 
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context,
                ReminderListActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder
                .create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ReminderListActivity.class);


        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack


        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        // notificationID allows you to update the notification later  on.


        mNotificationManager.notify(999, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 4):

LocalBroadcastManager looks like a better solution: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html Create your own custom Intent action, broadcast it to your process, and make sure any activity etc. is registered as a receiver for that intent.

Comment: My understanding is: An iPhone local notification, is a communication from your app to the user. LocalBroadcastManager on Android is a communication from one part of your app to another part of your app. I don't think LocalBroadcastManager is relevant to the question, but correct me if I'm wrong.