# How to make my app push notifications from my content?

Tags: android

I am doing an proverb app. It has 80+ Categories and in each category it has 30+proverbs. I am working on it with android studio. Now I want to make my app give a random proverb from all the categories daily as a notification. I need to know how to do it.

Comment: Could you give some more information as to what Data structure are you using for storing these proverbs?
Is it a single Collection or multiple collections corresponding to each category?

Answer (score 0):

The first answer for this question seems to be what you need.

[Local Notifications in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076165/local-notifications-in-android)