# How to call an alert when the app is in the background?

Tags: android, alert

I have an app that use the gps in the background, and in some situations I want to show an alert when the app is in the background: https://github.com/Tapadoo/Alerter

and works fine in the foreground but doesnt work in the background, how can i show that in background?
here is my code:

```
                    Alerter.create(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Alert Title")
                        .setText("Alert text...")
                        .show();
```

Comment: Raise a notification when you are in the background.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background

Comment: @AchalUrankar what is the use of checking if my app is in foreground or backgroun?

Comment: if app goes in background you ll receive an event and then you can generate a notification telling user app wont work in background or maybe start a foreground service that will make your app run

Answer (score 0):

To deal with anything related to UIs, use `Handler`.

**Option 1**

```java
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Alerter.create(MainActivity.this)
    .setTitle("Alert Title")
    .setText("Alert text...")
    .show();
  }
});
```

**Option 2**

```java
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
  public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
   Alerter.create(MainActivity.this)
    .setTitle("Alert Title")
    .setText("Alert text...")
    .show();
    return true;
  }
}).sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Comment: doesn't work :c

Comment: @RicardoCasimiro -- You might wanna try the other one.

Comment: still doesn't work :c  now i'm trying this https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You need the app to be on the foreground to access the Main Thread to display an AlertDialog on the UI. When your app is in the background it cannot access the UI but you can use the `Handler` suggested above by @Darkman.

You can also launch a [notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use local notification instead of using alert dialog.Please try below link for more information related to notifications.

[Local Notifications in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076165/local-notifications-in-android?rq=1)